# NMinimize/NMaximize is unable to generate initial points

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

*Mathematica 10* generates a warning that it is unable to generate initial points for numerical optimization problems. I picked a particularly simple example. The problem goes away when `Abs` is dropped.

```
NMinimize[{x + y, x >= 0 && Abs[x + 10 y + 100] <= 1}, {x, y}]
```

> *NMinimize::incst: "NMinimize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints {-1+Abs[100+x+10\ y]<=0}. The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points. Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution."*

Despite the warning, *Mathematica* computes the correct solution. How can I get rid of the warning?

Comment: You can use `Off`.

Comment: True but I prefer to understand why Mathematica generates the warning and what it needs not to generate it.

Comment: One way that works is to replace `Abs[expr]<=val` with `expr<=val&&-expr<=val`. I do not know whether this will work in general but I expect it to be useful when `expr` is linear (`NMinimize` uses some linear programming to get initial points).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a glimpse into the workings of `NMinimize` by turning on the debug-printing:

```
Block[{Optimization`NMinimizeDump`dbPrint = Print},
 NMinimize[{x + y, x >= 0 && Abs[x + 10 y + 100] <= 1}, {x, y}]
 ]
```

It seems at a cursory glance that it decided to search for points in the rectangle:

```
{{x,0.,2.},{y,-1,1}}
```

In this region it found zero of the three points it needs for the default Nelder-Mead method.

However, sometimes simplifying the constraints helps:

```
NMinimize[{x + y, 
  Reduce[x >= 0 && Abs[x + 10 y + 100] <= 1, {x, y}, Reals]}, {x, y}]

(*  {-10.1, {x -> 0., y -> -10.1}}  *)
```

No messages.

Answer (score 10):

Documentation states: "This error can typically be avoided by providing starting values for the variable".

Lets try to find these values:

```
 FindInstance[{x >= 0, Abs[100 + x + 10 y] <= 2}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 0, y -> -(49/5)}}

```
FindInstance[{x >= 1, Abs[100 + x + 10 y] <= 1}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 1, y -> -10}}

Lets try:

```
 NMinimize[{x + y, 
      x >= 0 && Abs[x + 10 y + 100] <= 1}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, -10, -49/5}}]
```

> {-10.1, {x -> 0., y -> -10.1}}

And no error report.

Comment: In the answer, you use two points satisfying the constraints rather than one. Is it necessary to do so? In case it isn't, would the proper syntax be ``{{x,0},{y,-10}}``? I couldn't find this info in the online documentation for NMinimize.

Comment: @Patricio Mathematica has a lot of undocumented features and commands. Your simply should try. Note, however,  that by specifying one and two point condition your automatically use different Minimization methods.

Comment: I was trying as you answered. I get the message ``Maximize::ivar: {x,0.23}`` is not a valid variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok. I see. I typed ``Maximize``instead of ``NMaximize``. When I use ``NMaximize`` it asks for a lower and and upper bound. Thanks.