# Why is the plot of low quality produced?

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Stydying [the modulus of continuity](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Continuity,_modulus_of) of $\sqrt x \log(x)$ in version 13.1
on Windows 10, I execute

```
g[\[Delta]_?NumericQ]:=NMaximize[{RealAbs[Sqrt[x]*Log[x]-Sqrt[y]*Log[y]],RealAbs[x-y]<\[Delta]&&x>0&&y>0},{x,y}]
```

which works relatively well, for example,

```
g[0.000001][[1]]
```

> `1.09893*10^-6`

and a warning

> NMaximize::incst: NMaximize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints
> {-0.00001+RealAbs[x-y]<=0}. The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points.
> Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution

However, the plot

```
Plot[g[t][[1]], {t, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50,  PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]

is simply incorrect (The modulus under consideration is asymptotically equivalent to $\delta$ as $\delta \to 0$ from above.) and of low quality. Also a warning

> NMaximize::incst: NMaximize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints {-0.0000256667+RealAbs[x-y]<=0}.
> The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points.
> Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution

is produced.
What is the reason and how to fix it?

Edit. A typo: $\sqrt x \log (x)$ instead of $x\log (x)$.

PS. My claim "The modulus under consideration is asymptotically equivalent to $\delta$ as $\delta \to 0$ from above" is not correct. It should be "The modulus under consideration is asymptotically equivalent to $-\sqrt \delta \log (\delta)$ as $\delta \to 0$ from above" instead of. In view of it this is rather a problem of `NMaximize`.

Comment: Well, this may seem obvious, but have you tried "Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points", since that is explicitly the suggestion given in the warning? Does that make it any better?

Comment: @MarcoB: Thank you for your interest to the question.  Can you kindly explain how " to change the initial region or specifying explicit initial points"? TIA.  As I understand it,  `NMaximize` does not take into account  `x>0&&y>0`.

Comment: Seems related : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65608/nminimize-nmaximize-is-unable-to-generate-initial-points.

Comment: @userrandrand: Thank you, but I don't  think so.  The problem under consideration   consists in  that `NMaximize` produces the correct answer despite a warning, but `Plot` doesn't.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is exactly but `NMinimize` needs help with the initial choices and you can maybe use the undocumented method by Acus in that link to provide those points.

Comment: @userrandrand: When I follow the advice from the link, i.e. replace `RealAbs[x-y]<\[Delta]&&x>0&&y>0` by the result of `Reduce[RealAbs[x - y] < \[Delta] && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, Reals]`, I obtain the same warning and a wrong result for `\[Delta]==0.000001`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I tried the reduce method and I did not see much improvement. My last comment was about the second answer using `FindInstance` and specifying initial conditions. I saw that the syntax for specifying initial conditions is also in the Possible Issues section of Nminize. I did not try specifying the initial conditions though.

Comment: What is wrong in my question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I understand now, the problem is caused by `NMaximize` which finds for small $\delta$s the local maximum $\approx \delta$ with $x$ and $y$ near $1$, but not the true supremum $\approx -\sqrt \delta \log (\delta)$ with $x$ near $0$ and $y$ near $\delta$ (or vice versa). This is solved by indicating initial points. We also redefine the function $\sqrt x \log(x)$
at $x=0$ as $0$ , i.e. its limit from above.

```
g[\[Delta]_?NumericQ] :=  NMaximize[{RealAbs[ Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x]*Log[x], x > 0}, 
{0, x == 0}}] -  Piecewise[{{Sqrt[y]*Log[y], y > 0}, {0, y == 0}}]], 
RealAbs[x - y] < \[Delta] && x > 0 && y > 0}, {x, y}, 
Method -> {"RandomSearch",  "InitialPoints" -> {{\[Delta]/2, \[Delta]}, {0.9,  0.9 - \[Delta]/2}}}]
```

and (On my comp its execution takes about an hour.)

```
Plot[g[t][[1]], {t, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: What is wrong in my answer?

Comment: I would imagine this is not an actual bugfix.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

g[δ_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaximize[{RealAbs[Sqrt[x]*Log[x] - Sqrt[y]*Log[y]], 
   RealAbs[x - y] < δ && x > 0 && y > 0}, {x, y}]
```

This definition of `g` uses machine precision irrespective of the precision of the input.

```
g[1.0`20*^-6] // Quiet

(* {1.09893*10^-6, {x -> 0.881505, y -> 0.881504}} *)

% // Precision

(* MachinePrecision *)
```

To maintain the precision of the input, change the definition

```
g[δ_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaximize[{RealAbs[Sqrt[x]*Log[x] - Sqrt[y]*Log[y]], 
   RealAbs[x - y] < δ && x > 0 && y > 0}, {x, y},
  WorkingPrecision -> Precision[δ]]

g[1.0`20*^-6] // Quiet

(* {0.55920273531026729167, {x -> 4.1794203324282570736*10^-7, 
  y -> 0.022426933542128677995}} *)

% // Precision

(* 20. *)
```

Note that these results are radically different from the first result.

The results are generally unstable; however, the following instance works.

```
Plot[g[t][[1]], {t, 0, 1},
  WorkingPrecision -> 40,
  PlotPoints -> 40,
  MaxRecursion -> 5] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: I am out of MMA so I'll respond later. Now  try $x=0.01^3$ and $y,=0.01$.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to answer the question (Especially `Queit`s are impressive.). Unfortunately, you haven't seen the heart of the problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276423/still-bug-in-reduce) is another answer of you of such sort which also does not make a good impression.